# NPM react-native-custom-timer-notification

Tags: reactjs, react-native, timer, countdown

[image]

[image]

Hello friends, I'm in doubt, I was wondering if you guys can help me. I'm doing a project in React Native where I need push notifications to contain a timer/countdown and that they can pause/start tasks and that countdown. It's been a challenge for me. I would like to do as the notifications of the app Pomodoro, which pause tasks through them and warn you how much time is left to finish a task. I found nothing about on the internet
I just found the dependency react-native-custom-timer-notification in the NPM website, if you know any other dependency that you can do that, please pass me

```
Usage
payload sent will be received when click or canceled
title Title of the notification
body Body of the notification
id unique number
date Time at which zero comes

import { TimerNotification, onEvent } from "react-native-custom-timer-notification";

// ...

// onclick and cancel listner
onEvent(event=>{
console.log(event)
});

// Remove timer 
RemoveTimer(160211114);

//Trigger notification
  TimerNotification({
      payload: JSON.stringify('notificationOpen?.data'),
      title: 'My notification',
      body: 'Much longer text that cannot fit one line... ',
      id: 160211114,
      remove: false, // optional
      foreground: false,
      date: new Date(Date.now() + 20000),
      isCountDown: true, // false for positive timer 
      setCustomContentView:true // optional
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

now react-native-custom-timer-notification v0.8 supports full scale custom notification. i think this might help you in this case. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-custom-timer-notification

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).